# 2nd order derivative with transformation of independent variable of 2nd order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations, transformation, change-of-variable

$$  \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} +a_{1}\left(x\right)\frac{dy}{dx} +a_{0}\left(x\right)   y=F\left(x\right) \tag{1}   $$

$$a_{0}\left(x\right),a_{1}\left(x\right),F\left(x\right)~ \text{are predefined}   $$

$$  t:= \xi\left(x\right) \tag{2}  $$

$$  \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx}= \frac{dy}{dt}\xi'\left(x\right)\tag{3}   $$

$$  \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2}= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right) \tag{4}  $$

$$ = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\xi'\left(x\right)\right)  $$

$$ = \xi''\left(x\right)\frac{dy}{dt}+ \underbrace{\xi'\left(x\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)}_{=:A}   $$

$$ = \xi''\left(x\right)\frac{dy}{dt}+ \underbrace{\left( \xi'\left(x\right) \right)^{2} \frac{d^{2}y}{dt^2}}_{\text{how this can be derived?} }   $$

$$  A= \xi'\left(x\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right) $$

$$ = \xi'\left(x\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{dy}{dx}  \frac{dx}{dt}\right)~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{my hand stopped from here}   $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote for clarity $\frac{dy}{dt}=v(t)$. Then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{dy}{dt}\right)=\frac{dv(t(x))}{dx}
=\frac{dv}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^2}\cdot\xi'(x).
$$